# Date date difference in years in oracle DB

Tags: oracle10g

I am using Oracle DB and trying to find the date difference in years. 
I googled and find out I can use `DateDiff` function. 
When I am using this function:

```
select datediff(year, date_1, date_2) as Age_Diff 
 from employee
```

I am getting an error

```
ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier.
```

Please suggest what is wrong in this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DATEDIFF` is not a function that exists in Oracle.

What, exactly, does it mean to you to get a difference between two dates in years?  For example, if you are given dates of 2010-04-01 and 2012-01-01, what is the expected output?  The difference is 1 year and 9 months so would that be 1.75?  Or should we count the number of days in those 9 months vs. the number of days in a year and divide the answer to get something slightly different than 1.75?

My first guess is that you want

```
SELECT months_between( date_1, date_2 )/12 years_between
  FROM employee
```

If you want to ignore any fractional part of a year

```
SELECT floor( months_between( date_1, date_2 )/12) floor_years_between
  FROM employee
```

Comment: Justin, the example which you gave, if that is the scenario I want the output as 1.

Comment: @Mohit224 - If you are saying that you want to ignore any fractional part of a year, then you probably want to add a `FLOOR` call.  I updated my answer.

Comment: it works. Thanks. I also tried this select TO_CHAR(ROUND(date_1, -date_2)/365) from employee

Comment: But I guess this is a wrong way to do because it ignores leap year. I might use the way you told me. Thanks again @Justin.